# how to get pandas pct_change result in percents?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm using pandas's example to do what I want to do:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([90, 91, 85])
>>> s
0    90
1    91
2    85
dtype: int64
```

then the `pct_change()` is applied to this series:

```
>>> s.pct_change()
0         NaN
1    0.011111
2   -0.065934
dtype: float64
```

okay, fair enough, but `Percentage Increase = [ (Final Value - Starting Value) / |Starting Value| ] × 100`

so the results should actually be `[NaN, 1.11111%, -6.59341%]`.
how would I get this `*100` part that the `pct_change()` didn't run for me?

Comment: `print(s.pct_change()*100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply multiply the result by `100` to get what you want:

```
In [712]: s.pct_change().mul(100)
Out[712]: 
0         NaN
1    1.111111
2   -6.593407
dtype: float64
```

If you want the result to be a `list`  of these values, do this:

```
In [714]: l = s.pct_change().mul(100).tolist()

In [715]: l
Out[715]: [nan, 1.1111111111111072, -6.593406593406592]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating functions:

.pct_change().multiply(100)

following the desired df operation. You could concatenate more functions before or after.